# JSON string returned from test site includes extra characters preventing json_decode from working

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to learn about transferring data between servers. There is a test API on line containing json data. I tried the following:-

```
    <?php
// Initiate curl session in a variable (resource) $curl_handle = curl_init();

$url = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees"; // website sample API data

// Set the curl URL option curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// This option will return data as a string instead of direct output curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute curl & store data in a variable $curl_data = curl_exec($curl_handle);

curl_close($curl_handle);

// Write the JSON string
// echo $curl_data; // the above writes the JSON string ok

// Now try decoding to PHP array
$character = json_decode($curl_data); 
echo $character[1]->employee_name; 
// this throws an error 'Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp64\www\curlex\curlget.php on line 24' 
?>
```

The string returned has the following content (stripped down to 2 entries for clarity):-

```
    {"status":"success","data":[{"id":"1","employee_name":"Tiger Nixon","employee_salary":"320800","employee_age":"61","profile_image":""},{"id":"2","employee_name":"Garrett Winters","employee_salary":"170750","employee_age":"63","profile_image":""}]}
```

I imagine json_decode fails because of the `{"status":"success","data":`preamble? How can this be resolved please?

Comment: Would `trim($curl_data)` not sort it?

Comment: Seems valid to me, at least I can parse it properly, assuming that the returned content you gave in your question is what you get back. Are you sure the problem is not maybe somewhere else in the JSON string?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you have ommited the second parameter from `json_decode()` function, which if not set, will parse the string to an object, instead of an array.

You can find the documentation for this function [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), what you are looking for it in your case, is the `assoc` parameter.

On the other hand, the example you show returns the sought `employee_name` inside another property, and not in the main property (namely `data`).

Try providing `true` as the second parameter to the function:

```
$character = json_decode($curl_data, true);
echo $character[1]['employee_name'];
```

But this will only work, if the example of the data is not accurate. If that example is accurate, to get the `employee_name` of the second data element, use:

```
$character = json_decode($curl_data, true);
echo $character['data'][1]['employee_name'];
```

Note, that php arrays are zero based, so if you want to get the first element out of an array, you should refer to it's 0th property.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this:

```
$character = json_decode($curl_data); 
echo $character->data[1]->employee_name;
```

Comment: All suggestions are much appreciated.  I'll look into them carefully after the weekend.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who offered help.   I hadn't realised that the returned string resulted in a two-dimensional array.   I was misled by the web site which gave me the link to the freely available test data.